# do not run systemd service when another service ran sucessfully

Tags: linux, fedora, systemd, systemd-unit

I have two services for an application:

1. healthcheck- which check the health of a system and attempts restart when the validation fails.
2. rollback- when multiple restart attempts fails to pass the healthcheck, it does the rollback to the previous version.

the unit file looks like this for health check:

```
[Unit]
Description=greenboot Health Checks Runner
Before=boot-complete.target
OnFailureJobMode=fail

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/greenboot/greenboot health-check
Restart=no

[Install]
RequiredBy=boot-complete.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and rollback

```
[Unit]
Description=Greenboot rollback
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=multi-user.target ostree-finalize-staged.service greenboot.service
Wants=local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target
ConditionNeedsUpdate=|/etc
ConditionNeedsUpdate=|/var

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/greenboot/greenboot rollback
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

rollback has other set of trigger conditions including a grub variable,
How can I ensure the the health-check service does not run when rollback run with exit code 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of the `OnFailure=` in health check to activate rollback when it fails, and `SuccessAction=reboot` in rollback to automatically reboot the system after your "rollback" operation finishes successfully.

In both units, IMHO, `RemainAfterExit=true` is unwanted.
*(Well at least in rollback)*

Only health check should contain an `[Install]` section because the other should only be activated on failures...

---

To properly answer the topic title, without regarding the use-case of the poster:

1. You should make use of `ConditionPathExists=!/some/path/filename`, in service "A" to prevent it being run when that file exists.
2. And create that file in the other service "B" in an `ExecStartPost=` directive, to prevent the first service "A" to start, when this service "B" exits successfully.